# How can I set playbook-level variables in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to set variables in a playbook so that they're accessible throughout the entire rest of the playbook at the playbook level rather than the host level. An example (where the `machine_mode` variable is passed in from command line):

```
- name: configure and install everything for the new boxes
  sudo: True
  hosts: new_hosts
  vars: [
      docker_required_roles: "['app_server', 'other_app_server']",
      pip_required_roles: "['some_server', 'other_server']",
      docker_required: "{{ machine_mode }} in docker_required_roles",
      pip_required: "{{ machine_mode }} in pip_required_roles"
    ]
  pre_tasks:
  - name: Gathering ec2 facts
    action: ec2_facts
  roles:
  #install docker and pip when required
  - { role: bobbyrenwick.pip, when: "pip_required"}
  - { role: angstwad.docker_ubuntu, when: "docker_required"}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this, it breaks with `error while evaluating conditional: dev in pip_required_roles`. Is there some other way I can define those variables so they're accessible through the whole playbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're misunderstanding where your playbook is falling over.

The error is telling you that it can't evaluate the conditional that you have put on the pip role as you are passing it the string literal `"dev in pip_required_roles"` rather than `true` or `false`.

Instead you need to get Ansible to evaluate your conditional statement properly to give you a boolean for your conditional role. You can do this by changing your vars block like this:

```
- name: configure and install everything for the new boxes
  sudo: True
  hosts: all
  vars:
    - docker_required_roles: ['app_server', 'other_app_server']
    - pip_required_roles   : ['some_server', 'other_server']
    - docker_required      : machine_mode in docker_required_roles
    - pip_required         : machine_mode in pip_required_roles
  roles:
  #install docker and pip when required
  - { role: bobbyrenwick.pip, when: "pip_required"}
  - { role: angstwad.docker_ubuntu, when: "docker_required"}
```

This changes your string literals for `docker_require_roles` and `pip_required_roles` variables into lists and then the `docker_required` and `pip_required` variables into conditions using Python's `in` operator (notice the lack of double quotes around them).

As a minor note I've also adjusted the vars block to use [YAML's list syntax](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics) rather than your chosen Python style syntax but that's more of a personal preference than anything else. You could also break down the lists for `docker_require_roles` and `pip_required_roles` variables to use the YAML syntax as well like this but for some reason that looks slightly more awkward to me:

```
  ...
  vars:
    - docker_required_roles:
      - 'app_server'
      - 'other_app_server'
    - pip_required_roles   :
      - 'some_server'
      - 'other_server'
    - docker_required      : machine_mode in docker_required_roles
    - pip_required         : machine_mode in pip_required_roles
  roles:
    ...
```

As to the wider idea of what you are tying to accomplish it looks like you might be better off doing this with different inventory files and group vars.

Comment: This will not do what you hope. The value of the `pip_required` variable will be a string `"pip_required": "machine_mode in pip_required_roles"` not a boolean. Ansible will only automatically treat a string as a jinja2 expression for the `when:` property. Otherwise, you need curly braces to make it explicit.

Comment: Notice I don't have quotes on the right hand side. Then it's not a string. Quick testing shows it evaluates okay at least on `1.9.4`

Comment: When I print it out with `debug: var=pip_required` on ansible 1.9.4, it's a string.

Comment: Not tried that but it at least conditionally executes things properly if you try my example play with `-e "machine_mode=app_server"` and `-e "machine_mode=dev"`

Comment: Yes I can confirm it seems to evaluate correctly despite the `debug` task showing it as a string.

Comment: Weirdly, this only seems to work when specifying variables in YAML format. When I try to do the same specifying variables in Python format, it doesn't work. Still the answer is correct and the easiest one, so marking correct. Overall this whole thing makes me wish Ansible didn't have so many competing ways of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

This vars as booleans thing gets tricky. Here's what I was able to get to work:

```
vars:
  docker_required_roles: ['app_server', 'other_app_server']
  pip_required_roles: ['some_server', 'other_server']
  docker_required: '{{"{{machine_mode}}" in docker_required_roles}}'
  pip_required: '{{"{{machine_mode}}" in pip_required_roles}}'
tasks:
  - debug: var=pip_required
  - debug: var=pip_required
    when: '{{pip_required | bool}}'
```

Note for the lists of role name strings, just use actual YAML to denote them properly, not a string of python code.

For the references, you need the extra curly braces around it to get ansible to run it through jinja2 and evaluate the "in" expression instead of just leaving you with the string `"dev in docker_required_roles"`.

When referencing the variable, you **must** always remember to use the `bool` filter to avoid the string `"False"` being interpreted as truthy.